# How can users stay logged into my Flutter app?

Tags: authentication, flutter

I want to add persistent login functionality into my Flutter app similar to other apps like Instagram and Twitter without using Firebase and have been unable to find any resources that show me how to do so.

I'm very new to Flutter so please go easy on me. Thank you!

P.S Flutter doctor doesn't show any problems.

Comment: check out `sharedPreference` plugin

Comment: @nonybrighto but on their page it says that it shouldn't be used to store critical data. I want to store an API token given by my API. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: `SharedPreference` is where I store my tokens and I guess that is what most people do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ever use `SharedPreference` to store tokens. When you're developing a native android application you should use `AccountManager`. As for flutter use `flutter_secure_storage`. I've seen alot of teams using it to save auth tokens.